# Send data to Mosquitto installed on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, ssh, sensor

I'm really new here and I have a question about the Raspberry Pi 3B+. I developed a little IoT application. Basically I read values from a sensor and then send them on my broker topic via Mosquito.

Mosquitto is running on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ at the office. The question is:
if I have another sensor at home and I want to send those values to the same topic, how can I access Mosquitto running on my Raspberry Pi?

I have very little experience in programming and `Iot`, so if someone could help me it would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do some research on either/and VPN and port-forwarding. And strictly this isn't a Raspberry Pi question, its about network and firewalls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a minimum you should be discussing this with your IT support at work.  Never trust free advice from the Internet where security and privacy is involved :-)

Saying that, here is my free advice:

The simplest way would be to use a broker based on the Internet that you can reach both from home and work.

A search will turn up a few free ones (I like Adafruit IO as a basic free service as it's documentation and community support is fine) or low cost fully supported ones.

The second option would be to create a VPN between home and the office BUT I have to strongly recommend that you talk to your works IT support before trying anything like this.

The last option would be to have your work IT support to open a port on the firewall to allow the MQTT traffic to reach the broker.  Again I highly recommend you discuss this with your IT support and understand how you are to protect the Pi from intrusion attempts (firewall, updates, fail2ban as a minimum).

My last comment is to be very careful as projects like this can grow and before you know, corporate security can be significantly compromised by careless scope creep.  Remember the Pi user is a known target and default user and password should be disabled and changed if external access is possible.  See the old NASA story [here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/nasa-hacked-because-of-unauthorized-raspberry-pi-connected-to-its-network/) - OK I assume you are not the size of NASA but any IP address is vulnerable and often scanned (inc home).  Legal ramifications can be high...

Comment: Ok, thanks! Could be a solution to use AWS or IBM services instead of raspberry?